# Is Stack Overflow too aggressive in closing questions?

Tags: discussion

This is how I use Stack Overflow: I search for a question on Google, and if a Stack Overflow result shows up, I click on it and view the question and answers, and up-vote if I find the information useful. Using it this way, it does not matter if there are hundreds of questions that are "too broad" or "not a good fit for the Q/A format" or "not likely to be useful to others". I simply don't see those, unless they are relevant to what I am searching for.

So, is it not better to have lots of questions of which any of them will only show up when people are searching for them? Or is it better to close questions that people might actually be searching for, in order to have a "cleaner" overall set of questions?

To me, it does not seem to matter if there are lots of junk questions on the site, if no one will actually see them!

My personal opinion is that there are plenty of questions that get mob-voted closed (I guess that's fun for some people maybe?), that really could be helpful for a subset of people out there. If the rest of us don't see it, what's the problem?

I think legitimate reasons to close questions are 1) they are duplicate or 2) they are very poor quality where it really would not be very comprehensible to someone searching for it.

Comment: Please link to or explan an example that is currently deemed _""too broad" or "not a good fit for the Q/A format" or "not likely to be useful to others""_ that you would like to see on the site. By answering such questions (that are ultimately only helpful for one or very few people) answerers aren't answering better questions that help the site and community more.

Comment: You do realize that being closed (especially as a dupe) doesn't necessarily mean they are useless and won't ever be seen, right?

Comment: @codeMagic OP's point is that as long as people won't search for the terms used in closed questions, those won't show up for them, so they aren't taking up space in the search results or something like that.

Comment: @CodeCaster It does not degrade the site to allow more questions, especially the ones that have a lot of up-votes but get closed anyway. What does hurt the site are overly aggressive voters who dissuade and turn people away from the site, and these are people who do want to learn.

Comment: OK, so you have at least three close reasons already: duplicate, very poor quality, and off topic. What about a question that reads "Hey guyz what is the best IDE for building an Android app?" Should it get to stay?

Comment: @pkr298 upvotes on such question usually mean _"I want to know that too!"_. That doesn't make it a valid question for SO, however in demand the possible answers are. Perhaps a tutorial or blog is needed in those cases, which are inherently different than Q&As on SO.

Comment: If they are helpful but no longer on topic and were well received then they most likely won't be deleted. What's the problem?

Comment: In short, yes! SO is too aggressive IMHO. There is a tyranny in the use of Close: Off Topic and such, including 17+ down votes on this entirely legitimate and useful question. This discourages new folks like myself from participating. Some stack moderators are too quick to judge and the mechanism to overturn these decisions on meta is too time consuming. I'd rather leave it to non-admins to decide on most Close decisions and live with some off topics rather than aim for such high quality that it excludes more good questions than it helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your argument is basically: if there's a buyer (the asker), and a seller (someone willing to answer), and it bothers no-one else, why not just leave them alone to their transaction?

Who are we to impose on them our idea of what a good question should look like?

That's not a bad thought as such, but it's not the whole story.

If you want a healthy marketplace of questions that *actually get quality answers,* you need a base of answerers who are willing to return to it *every day.*

The belief you'll find most of us here subscribe to is this: to attract experts who can answer questions, you need to provide some level of quality.

No expert is going to give away slices of their valuable time to answer the same boring, bad questions over and over again. Maybe for a while. But not in the long term.

From *this* point of view, allowing any kind of question *is* damaging the site. Especially when there's more than 8,000 of them *every day*, many (if not most) of them very bad quality.

Because it's degrading the overall quality of the place, making it more like a place that an expert in their field *doesn't* want to be in.

Now you can argue that Stack Overflow, in its quest to maintain its ideas of quality, has become overzealous, and is now closing many a good question because it doesn't adhere to a set of rules that has grown more and more specific and narrow over time.

That it's become a scary place for newcomers not familiar with the site's arcane rules.

And you may well be right!

Even Jeff Atwood, one of the site's founders, has said that he never expected the community to become this narrow in its focus. And he certainly never was the *laissez faire* type when it comes to quality.

But to make an argument that even stands a *chance* of being taken seriously, you'll have to put more on the table than just the vague notion that we should just allow *any* kind of question because it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: Keeping the answerers happy is a good point. I think Stack Overflow could broaden its acceptance of which questions are allowed, based on how helpful people find them. It's sad when questions that have more than 10 upvotes get closed anyway.

Comment: I agree that poor quality and duplicate questions should be closed with a rigorous approach. The OP focus is more or equally about "too broad" or "off topic" or "not likely to be useful" which your answer doesn't so well apply to. If a few zealous moderators deem a question "too broad" or "off topic" but the community likes it, generally the moderators win because the threshold to overturn moderator decisions is too high and cos community folks have other priorities than debates on meta.

Answer (score 11):

When you're searching Google for answers to your programming questions, do you ever see results from Yahoo! Answers? Probably very rarely, at least in the past six years. That's because they allow you to ask anything you want, so their quality is quite low, and they don't get indexed as aggresively as Stack Overflow. By keeping the quality (relatively) high and on a focused topic, we make sure search engines can find the best content.

Comment: http://askville.amazon.com is a nice example too, although it's improved its front page *massively*

Comment: @Bill the Lizard That's not really true. The community base for Yahoo Answers aren't programmers, so people don't ask programming questions on Yahoo Answers. Yet, their questions do show up in search results, if you're searching for the same types of things that the Yahoo Answers community asks for. Allowing any question to be asked does not mean the quality is therefore lower.

Comment: @pkr298 Yes, people do ask programming question on Yahoo! Answers, and [since everyone has an opinion](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110620035408AAo6Thi) they get answered with all kinds of bad advice, which does mean that the average quality is lower.

Comment: We need to be aware though there's a growing circlejerk out there (reddit, hackernews, various others) in which it's cool to rant on SO where "power-hungry mods [sic] close anything interesting".

Comment: More than half the Closed: Off Topic questions I find via Google search provided exactly the info I needed to solve an urgent work challenge. I disagree that the issue is solely "pissed off users with bad questions". We are throwing the baby out with the bath water in some cases and need to find accommodation for some of these broader, off topic or opinion questions.